# NetSuite -Invalid search query - cant query tables under 'connect Browser'

Tags: python, netsuite, suiteql

I'm having a problem to query the data from netsuite with `get requests`. Every time I want to query a table which is under `connect Browser` I get a `bad request` error: `Invalid search query`

```
def post_sql(url, realm, token_key, token_secret, consumer_key, consumer_secret):
header_oauth = OAuth1(  client_key=consumer_key, client_secret=consumer_secret,
                        resource_owner_key=token_key, resource_owner_secret=token_secret,
                        signature_type='auth_header',
                        realm=realm,
                        signature_method='HMAC-SHA256')
conn = requests.post(url, headers={"Prefer":"transient"}, auth=header_oauth, json={
"q": 'SELECT * FROM Sales_reps'
    
  })

return conn.json()
```

But when I query tables from `analytics browser` it works perfectly after changing a table names slightly (transaction_lines into transactionline and so on).

Does anyone know what could be a problem?

This is the list of queries I want to perform:

```
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNTS
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTION_LINES
SELECT * FROM TRANSACTIONS
SELECT * FROM ITEMS
SELECT * FROM ENTITY
SELECT * FROM DEPARTEMENTS 
SELECT * FROM LOCATIONS
SELECT * FROM SALES_REPS
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES
SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS
SELECT * FROM ENTITY_STATUS
SELECT * FROM ENTITY_STATUS_HISTORY
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the error is because you are using the wrong scheme database to apply those queries. Remember that NetSuite has two DataBase with different table names.

Here you have a example of the different tables names on each scheme.

```html
    <table style="border:solid">
      <tr>
        <th style="border:solid">Scheme NetSuite.com Table</th>
        <th style="border:solid">Scheme NetSuite2.com Table</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border:solid">ACCOUNTS</td>
        <td style="border:solid">ACCOUNT</td>    
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border:solid">TRANSACTION_LINES</td>
        <td style="border:solid">TRANSACTIONLINE</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border:solid">TRANSACTIONS</td>
        <td style="border:solid">TRANSACTION</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="border:solid">SALES_REPS</td>
        <td style="border:solid">VENDOR</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I fixed this long ago, but your answer is correct.